# How to fix too_many_redirects with this PHP login set up

Tags: php, html, apache2, lamp, web-testing

I have a web server running LAMP. I have the website tbg.robotpidgeon.com set up to run the PHP login system that I copied from here (https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php).

Very basic login system using MySQLi.

In my apache2 config file for this web address, I have set up the virtual host and pointed it to where the PHP files are located. However, when you go to the above address it generates an index of the PHP files.

When I try to set up the virtual host to land on the login or welcome page I get a too_many_redirects error. So I am assuming that I have created a loop when I set the virtual host document root to a specific PHP file?

What should I do so that when I go to the above address it goes to the login/register page?

Comment: Maybe you should rollback to apache2 default config, and put you code to the default path for checking code problem or apache2 problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The browser is stopping you from hammering the server with a bunch of
>   requests. This is most likely due to the `header()` sending you to a
>   page which in turn sends you to the same page (or page with the same
>   `header()`).
>
> In your session.php you have to destroy the session because it might
>   be set still but without that the query can find a existing user?
>
> To unset sessions do this:
>
> `unset();` for all the session variables
>   `unset($_SESSION['login_user']);` for a specific session